# curl_getinfo http_code returns 400 instead 404

Tags: php, curl

When I try to use curl_getinfo on a nonexisting page, it returns 400, but the fire bug show 404 status. Why?
The code i use, is from [manual](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.curl-getinfo.php)

Comment: Could you give an example of such a page? Mind you, syntactically it would have to be valid to be able to return a `404`...

Comment: What does Firebug have to do with curl?

Comment: for example http://www.google.ru/123.html

Comment: Google is not good place to test curl - Google has millions dolars and thousends firewalls to catch script/bot and redirect to different page (sometimes with captcha). Some other portals can do the same. Your script has to behave like browser used by human to get correct results from that kind portals :)